# The find linux command cannot delete files

Tags: shell, find

This is my shell command line:

```
find /home/ -depth -type f -iname "*php.jpg*" -o -iname "*php.gif*" -o -iname "*php.png*"  -o -iname "*php.txt*" -o -iname "*html.jpg*" -o -iname "*html.gif*" -o -iname "*html.png*" -iname "*php3.jpg*" -delete
```

My permission is root.

When I run this command line withdown `-delete`, I receive a list of files. But I cannot delete files with this command.

Something wrong?

Comment: The `-delete` flag is not available in all versions of `find`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this;

```
 find /home/  -type f \( -iname "*php.jpg*" -o -iname "*php.gif*" -o -iname "*php.png*"  -o -iname "*php.txt*" -o -iname "*html.jpg*" -o -iname "*html.gif*" -o -iname "*html.png*" -iname "*php3.jpg*" \)  -delete
```

You need to surround the multiple -names with brackets as above;

> "It is recommended that you enclose the file extensions in a bracket,
>   and also use the \ ( back slash) escape character as in the command."

Answer (score 1):

The `-delete` action is available only in some `find` versions (eg GNU `find`). It was introduced by BSD OSs. From [GNU findutils page](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html):

> The '-delete' action was introduced by the BSD family of operating systems.

You can use the more portable `-exec` action:

```
find /home/ -depth -type f \( -iname "*php.jpg*" -o -iname "*php.gif*" -o -iname "*php.png*"  -o -iname "*php.txt*" -o -iname "*html.jpg*" -o -iname "*html.gif*" -o -iname "*html.png*" -iname "*php3.jpg*" \) -exec rm -f {} \;
```

**Edit:**

Note that to apply the `-delete` action on all `-iname` expressions, you must group them using escaped parenthesis:

```
find /home/ -depth -type f \( -iname "*php.jpg*" -o -iname "*php.gif*" -o -iname "*php.png*"  -o -iname "*php.txt*" -o -iname "*html.jpg*" -o -iname "*html.gif*" -o -iname "*html.png*" -iname "*php3.jpg*" \) -delete
```

Comment: I tryed it, and nothing change. May be the return string have problem or somthing else.

When I run the comman: find /home/ -depth -type f -iname "*php.jpg*" -delete. It works, but when i run the command with multi name. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
find /home/ -depth -type f -iname "*php.jpg*" -o -iname "*php.gif*" -o -iname "*php.png*"  -o -iname "*php.txt*" -o -iname "*html.jpg*" -o -iname "*html.gif*" -o -iname "*html.png*" -iname "*php3.jpg*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```